# How can i get flume-ng to store logs in JSON format

Tags: json, flume

I have a Flume consolidator that writes an entry from a custom log to s3 bucket in AWS

the problem i am having is, it is not storing it in JSON format. I am using flume-ng (flume 1.2.0) as i have upgraded from flume-og (really just flume 0.9.4-cdh3u3). When i was using flume (og one), i had it default to moving logs in JSON format without any params set. Is it possible for flume-ng to parse log and set it to JSON format?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

my setup config is below

```
agent.sources = source1
agent.sinks = sink1
agent.channels = channel1

agent.sources.source1.type = netcat
agent.sources.source1.bind = localhost
agent.sources.source1.port = 4555

agent.sinks.sink1.type=hdfs
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = s3://KEY:SECRET@BUCKET/flume/apache/incoming
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = log-file-

agent.channels.channel1.type = memory
agent.channels.channel1.capacity = 1000
agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapactiy = 100

agent.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```